# problems passing data through view controllers (using segues) xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to create a basic app that takes info that the user puts in to display it on a second view controller.I have a button that `push(deprecated)` to ViewControllerTwo with a identifier that is "`calButtonPressed`" but then I want it to display *float BAC on a label* on ViewControllerTwo. The label just says nothing but it does go to the next ViewController.It also has no errors in the code. What can I do to fix this? Thanks :)

**Code on ViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"calButtonPressed"])
    {
        ViewControllerTwo *vc2 = (ViewControllerTwo *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc2.lblBAC.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", BAC];
    }
}
```

**Code on ViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblBAC;
```

Comment: Just to clarify the below comment, OUTLETS(!) are not yet set when `PrepareForSegue:sender:` is called. as mr. Taverne suggested, Just declare a public property in `ViewControllerTwo` class, and you can set its value without any issues. Then, in `ViewControllerTwo` `viewDidLoad` method, you can use this property to set the outlet text.

Comment: Thank  you so much, how do you do what you said? Can you please type out an example because Im kinda confused. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ViewCongtrollerTwo, add a property to hold the text until the view has been loaded.

```
@interface ViewControllerTwo () 

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *textFromlblBAC;

@end
```

Use this instead in your prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"calButtonPressed"])
{
    ViewControllerTwo *vc2 = (ViewControllerTwo *)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc2.textFromlblBAC = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", BAC];
}
```

And then also in ViewCongtrollerTwo, copy this value into the labels text field only after the text field has been created and the view has been loaded.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    viewControllerTwoLabel.text = self.textFromlblBAC;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind. Great job providing actual code to do it! This is a common mistake with segues.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set lblBAC because vc2's view has not yet loaded. Instead, declare a string property on vc2, set that in prepareForSegue, and then set lblBAC.text to that property in the viewDidLoad of vc2.